# Logic behind this automatic gate light

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, logic-gates

I was doing this circuit which I found on the Internet. My question is what is the logic behind the functioning of this circuit? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: How about a link to wherever you found it?

Answer (score 1):

You press the button, it rings the bell and turns on the light for a set amount of time if it's dark outside.

IC<sub>2</sub> is almost certainly a 555 timer chip.